# When to use sealed interface wrappers vs just an interface?

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns

When refactoring code like:

```
interface Offer {
    val sharedProperty: Property
}

class Product(...): Offer {
    override...
}

class Category(...): Offer {
    override...
}

fun Offer.doSomething(...) {
    when(this) {
        is Product -> ...
        is Category -> ...
        else -> <handle not supported implementation>
    }
}
```

I've recently been using this pattern quite a bit:

```
class Product(...)

class Category(...)

sealed interface Offer {

    val sharedProperty: Property

    class ProductOffer(
        val product: Offer
        override...
    ): Offer

    class CategoryOffer(
        val category: Category
        override...
    ): Offer
}

fun Offer.doSomething(...) {
    when(this) {
        is ProductOffer -> ...
        is CategoryOffer -> ...
    }
}
```

Now I realize the semantics and particularities this implies when containing an item vs being an item. I also realize consumers of my code won't be able to extend external classes with my sealed interface but I was wondering if there are other potential pitfalls from using this wrapping pattern?

Comment: Yes, consumers cannot implement your interface, but that's the point of a sealed interface, right? You don't want arbitrary implementations because your local code can only handle specific types, as it is handling specific types differently and exhaustively.